# Why there are no IEC C8 to NEMA 1-15R cables?

Tags: iec

Conntek has an IEC C8 to 1-15R adapter. C8 to CEE7/16 cables are dime a dozen on Aliexpress. Yet there are no C8 to 1-15R cables as far as I can tell. Is there an electronics/standard reason forbidding it?

Comment: I'm confused by what you're looking for. NEMA 1-15**R** is a receptacle/outlet & IEC 60320 C8 is AFAIK usually found as the power inlet on a device. A 1-15**P** to IEC C7 would make more sense.

Comment: https://conntekisi.com/c8-to-1-15r-plug-adapter in cable form.